# Comparing the value of a key in an array of objects to a variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table called follower_tb. The columns in the table are like this: follow_id (this is the primary key), follower_id(the id the person that followed another person), followed_id (the id of the person that is being followed).
In order to fetch the table, I wrote this sql statement.

```
SELECT p.participant_id,
       p.username,
       p.fullname,
       p.profile_pics,
       f.follow_id,
       f.follower_id,
       f.followed_id
FROM participant_tb p
JOIN follower_tb f ON ( p.participant_id = f.followed_id ) 
WHERE followed_id = 1 || follower_id =  1
```

I will be neglecting the participant_tb in my result and go straight to the main point. My result look like this

```js
[{
  follow_id: 1,
  follower_id: 1,
  followed_id: 2
}, {
  follow_id: 2,
  follower_id: 2,
  followed_id: 1
}, {
  follow_id: 3,
  follower_id: 1,
  followed_id: 3
}, {
  follow_id: 3,
  follower_id: 4,
  followed_id: 1
}]
```

from this, it means the persons with the id of 1 and the id of 2 are following each other. The person with with the id of 1 is following the person with the id of 3 but the person with the id of 3 is not following back. Lastly, the person with the id of 4 is following the person with the id of 1 but he/she is not following back.
I got the result into a scope (**$scope.allfollowing**) and I used ng-repeat (x in allfollowing) to loop through at the view. 
The owner of the account(the person with an id of 1) already has his/her id saved in a scope( **$scope.signedin_id**).
My main issue is that, I want to display only one of these two buttons using ng-if of angularjs. The first button is the unfollow (this should be displayed in the first case because the two are following each other. It should also be displayed in the second case, because the person with the id of 1 is already following the person with the id of 3), the second button is the followback( this should be displayed in the third case because the person with the id of 1 is yet to follow the person with the id of 4).
I could have used something like this:

```
 ng-if="x.follower_id == signedin_id" 
 ng-if="x.followed_id == signedin_id"
```

But the problem is that: for the person with the is of 2(who is following Id of 1 and he is also following back), both buttons will be displayed, how can I solve this problem?

I will be glad if someone show me an effective way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is how you want to display the buttons, but maybe you could do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in allfollowing">
    <button ng-if="x.follower_id == signedin_id" click="unfollow(x.followed_id)"> 
       Unfollow {{x.followed_id}}
    </button>
    <button ng-if="x.followed_id == signedin_id && notfollowed(x.follower_id)" click="followback(x.follower_id)"> 
       Follow {{x.follower_id}} back
    </button>
</div>
```

---

```
notfollowed(string id){
    for x in allfollowing{
        if (x.followed_id == id){
        return false
        }
    }
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, the problem u have with this approach is that: Both buttons will be displayed for the person with the id of 2 because he is following and at the same time he is a follower of the person with an ID of 1

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood i thought you wanted both buttons for that case.

Comment: I have included a simple way to check that the "follow back" button doesn't appear if he is already following him